# Reporting in ES/DDD Microservices

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am just starting out with ES/DDD and I have a question how one is supposed to do reporting in this architecture.  Lets take a typical example, where you have a Customer Aggregate, Order Aggregate, and Product Aggregate all independent.

Now if i want to run a query across all 3 aggregates and/or services, but that data is each in a separate DB, maybe one is SQL, one is a MongoDB, and one something else. How is one supposed to design or be able to run a query that would require a join across these aggregates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should design the `Reporting` as a simple **read-model/projection**, possible in its own `bounded context` (`BC`), that just listen to the relevant `events` from the other bounded contexts (`Customer BC`, `Ordering BC` and `Inventory BC`) and builds the needed reports with full data denormalization (i.e. at query time you won't need to query the original sources).

Because of events you won't need any `joins` as you could maintain a private local state attached to the `Reporting read-model` in which you can store temporary external models and query those temporary read-models as needed thus avoiding external additional queries to the other `BCs`.

An anti-corruption layer would not be necessary in this case as there would be no write-model involved in the `Reporting BC`.

Things are really as simple as that because you already have an event-driven architecture (you use `Event sourcing`).

UPDATE:

This particular solution is very handy in creating new reports that you haven't thought ahead of time. Every time you thing about a new report you just create a new Read-model (as in you write its source code) then you replay all the relevant events on it. Read-models are side-effect free, you can replay all the events (from the beggining of time) any time and as many time you want.

Read-model rebuilding is done in two situations:

1. you create a new Read-model
2. you modify an existing one by listening to a new event or the algorithm differs too much from the initial version

You can read more here:

1. [DDD/CQRS specialized forum - Grey Young is there!](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/dddcqrs/rebuilding$20AND$20projection)
2. [Event sourcing applied – the read model](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2015/07/16/event-sourcing-applied-the-read-model/)
3. [Writing an Event-Sourced CQRS Read Model](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2015/09/22/writing-an-event-sourced-cqrs-read-model/)
4. [A post in first group describing Read Model rebuilding](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/dddcqrs/twwfQde3RW4)

Or you can search about this using this text: `event sourcing projection rebuilding`

Comment: So does that imply that the Reporting BC would contain all of the events from the other bounded contexts because that seems like the only way to be able to query across all domain objects, or at least as the event from each of other BC's arrives to extract the pertinent piece of info and build up the entity in the Reporting BC.  Also, this would mean all reporting would have to be pre-planned, how would one add an additional report that required some data which was not previously being pulled from the arriving events ? So would you have to replay all events from the beginning and extract the

Comment: required data, for you to pull in your new report ? Again, it seems very complicated, from having to aggregate multiple events and create one record out of it, to having to replay events if an additional data element is later required for reporting purposes and needs to be extracted from the original events.  Please let me know if my understanding is correct, or if im way in left field, thanks !

Comment: I understand perfectly. This is not complicated, it is very simple in Event sourcing. What are you describing is called Read-model rebuilding. You do a full rebuild every time you create a new Read-model or you register (start listening) to a new event type in an existing Read-model. Rebuilding is well discussed.

Comment: "Also, this would mean all reporting would have to be pre-planned" -  this is the "falsest" statement ever regarding Event sourcing. Every time you invent/think_about_a new Read-model you write its source code then rebuild its state by replaying all interesting events.

Comment: There are tons of articles about Read-models (Projections). The main idea is that **you can** anytime and as many time as you want **replay all the events** in a read-model. Read-models do not have side effects!

Comment: You can read more here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/dddcqrs/rebuilding$20AND$20projection https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2015/07/16/event-sourcing-applied-the-read-model/ http://squirrel.pl/blog/2015/09/22/writing-an-event-sourced-cqrs-read-model/ https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/dddcqrs/twwfQde3RW4

Comment: Thanks for the link and info. Just to be clear by my comment "Also, this would mean all reporting would have to be pre-planned", I meant that you cannot just run any query because the data is not aggregated yet, so if you ever decide to run any type of query, first you will have to replay all of your events from all your BC's from which you require data as part of you query and create some model which can then be read. i guess it takes getting used to, as opposed to just going into db and querying your data.

Comment: When your report query will run under 0.0001 sec over 1,000,000 rows you will be happy and get used to quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

Domain-Driven Design is more concerned with the *command* side of things.  You should not attempt to query your domain as that leads to pain and suffering.

Each bounded context may have its own data store and that data store may be a different technology as you have stated.

For reporting you would use a reporting store.  How you get data into that store would either require each bounded context to publish events that the reporting BC would pick up and use to update the reporting store or you could make use of event sourcing where the reporting store would project the events into the relevant reporting structures.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but I thought the CQRS in DDD allows for reads and writes ? Regardless, this makes sense, but is it feasible for a large application to basically have to capture events from multiple services and then aggregate that into another data store and use that as the read store for analytics ?  It seems like a very cumbersome approach for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There are known practices to solve this.

One might be having a reporting context, which, as Eben has pointed out, will listen to domain events from other contexts and update its store. This of course will lead to issues, since this reporting context will be coupled to all services it reports from. Some might say this is a necessary evil but this is not always the case.

Another technique is to aggregate on-demand. This is not very complex and can be done on different layers/levels. Consider aggregation on the web API level or even on the front-end level, if your reporting is on the screen (not sent by mail as PDF, for example).
This is well known as UI composition and Udi Dahan has wrote an article about this, which is worth reading: [UI Composition Techniques for Correct Service Boundires](http://udidahan.com/2012/06/23/ui-composition-techniques-for-correct-service-boundaries/). Also, Mauro Servienti has wrote a blog post about this recently: [The secret of better UI composition](https://particular.net/blog/secret-of-better-ui-composition).

Mauro mentions two types of composition, which I mentioned above. The API/server-side composition is called *ViewModel Composition* in his post, and front-end (JavaScript) composition is mentioned in the *Client side composition process* section. Server-side composition is illustrated by this picture:

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment, it looks theortically do-able, but very infeasible. In this case, we are breaking everything up into microservices, which makes sense, but then trying to aggregate everything back up for reporting with each of the individual events or data pieces in this case arriving at different points in time. This seems like it can get very painful with a large application and bigger data set. How has your experience been with implementing DDD and ES for larger applications with heavy reporting and analytics requirements ?

Comment: Well, reporting context does make sense if it is the goal in itself. I am not talking about microservices, but since each bounded context has it's own persistence, some soft of data composition is required. Event-driven data synchronization is a very valid approach. The specific choice is always down to the combination of requirements and personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

DDD strategic modeling tools says:

Design two different models 1. Write Models (Handles Command Side) 2.Read Models (POCOs/POJOs) whatever u call them.